# listen to youtube api notification

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-cloud-run

when live video started on youtube channel , i want to know it and send to apple APN server. it' possible? I am ios developer and I am new on node.js.
I wrote these code for listen youtube

```
      const YouTubeNotifier = require('youtube-notification');
     
    const notifier = new YouTubeNotifier({
      hubCallback: 'https://youtube-server-i2ntcu76bq-uc.a.run.app/youtube/callback',
      port: 8080,
      path: '/youtube'
    });
    notifier.setup();
     
    notifier.on('notified', data => {
      console.log('New Video');
      console.log(
        `${data.channel.name} just uploaded a new video titled: ${data.video.title}`
      );
    });
 notifier.subscribe('UC1zAttFQKikWoKH3Vb39ETA');
```

My callback is :

https://youtube-server-i2ntcu76bq-uc.a.run.app/youtube/callback

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const axios = require("axios");

const apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3";
const apiKey = "API_KEY_GOES_HERE";
const channelId = "UC1zAttFQKikWoKH3Vb39ETA";

    // get an instance of router
var router = express.Router();


//https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=UC1zAttFQKikWoKH3Vb39ETA&key=AIzaSyAnY52Lr-hOku3fdxVQLIbm45TpZbDWzvw

    // home page route (http://localhost:8080)
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('im the home page!');
    });

router.get('/youtube/callback', (req, res) => {
    //console.log('here', req.body, req.query, req.params, req.headers)
    console.log('here', res.body)
    let query = req.query
    if('hub.challenge' in query){
        let channelID = query['hub.topic'].split('=').pop()
        /*if(!bot.youtube.pendingVerify.has(channelID)) {
            console.log('Invalid youtube hook sent to me', channelID, req.headers)
            return res.sendStatus(401)
        }*/
       /* bot.youtube.lease.set(channelID, Date.now() + (query['hub.lease_seconds'] * 1000))
        bot.youtube.pendingVerify.delete(channelID)*/
        //return res.status(202).send(query['hub.challenge'])
        
        //const responseText = req.query['hub.challenge'] || "no challenge" 
       // res.send(responseText)
    }
    return req.query['hub.challenge'] 
})

router.post('/youtube/callback', (req, res) => {
    console.log('here', res.body)
    //console.log('here post', req.body, req.query, req.params, req.headers)
 return req.query['hub.challenge'] 
   // let hmac = generateHMAC(req.query['hub.challenge'], 'very_secret', "sha1")
})
/*
function generateHMAC(hmac, secret, algo = 'sha256'){
    return `${algo}=${crypto.createHmac(algo, secret).update(hmac).digest('hex')}`
}
*/

    // apply the routes to our application
    app.use('/', router);

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
```

when i add video or live video on youtube ,`notifier.on('notified', data  )` not work. why i can't listen youtube and i have log on google cloud that :

FeedFetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html) https://youtube-server-i2ntcu76bq-uc.a.run.app/youtube/callback?hub.topic=https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml%3Fchannel_id%3DUC1zAttFQKikWoKH3Vb39ETA&hub.challenge=5437060724976338936&hub.mode=subscribe&hub.lease_seconds=432000
The request has been terminated because it has reached the maximum request timeout. To change this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout

how can i listen youtube ? please help

Comment: Hi, did you try increasing the maximum request timeout as suggested in the docs?

Comment: hi @ZeenathSN , yes i did 3600

Comment: I've just approved an edit that removed your API key from your code sample, but the value will still be visible in the post history. You should invalidate the key and generate a new one. Please be careful when posting credentials to SO.

Comment: If possible, can you try to check if the code is working on the local machine? So that we will know if the problem is with the Cloud Run or the code.

Comment: But callback function not will work on localhost . I tried on heroku Same problem :(